# biblatex: author and subbibliography

Tags: table-of-contents, biblatex, memoir

2 questions that have been bugging me forever now:

1 I have several `biblatex` entries that are some sort of publication without a specific `author`. I use them like this:

```
@booklet{name,
author = {Surpreme Court},
etc
}
```

This is just an example ofcourse, but now when i print my `bibliography` it will write it down as: Court, Surpreme. This because ofcourse i entered it as author. But i have a lot of `booklet` entries without a specific `author`. Whats the best way to make sure it just prints it as: Surpreme Court and not Court, Surpreme?

2 I have my subbibliography as: `\printbibliography[heading=subbliography]` etc

The manual says it should not put this in my TOC. Cuz then i would have to use `subbibintoc`

But for some reason it does put my `subbibliography` in my TOC. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With regard to your second question: It seems that cooperation between `memoir` and `biblatex` is not perfect -- bibliographies are included in the ToC by default, and you have to use the `memoir` command `\nobibintoc` to change this.

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\nobibintoc

\usepackage{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\nocite{*}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\printbibheading

\printbibliography[heading=subbibliography,title={First subbibliography}]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your first question must have been answered before here (and was, definitely, elsewhere): double braces!

```
author = {{Supreme Court}}
```

Question two needs a full minimal example to figure out what is going wrong, since different document classes behave differently, for example.

Comment: I am basically using a edited version of `memoir` im not home now but can post a mwe if needed tonight. 

Feel stupid about the firs question now, thx a lot!